Использование ngrok с WebSocket (или socket.io)
Я делаю сайт с крестиками-ноликами и для этого хочу использовать socket.io и ngrok, но когда я захожу на сайт web-socket не работает
server:
const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')
const { Server } = require('socket.io')
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express()
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: '*',
    })
)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Привет, мир!')
    console.log('res has been sent!')
})

const server = http.createServer(app)
const PORT = 3000
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('Sever has started!')
})

const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
        methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    },
})

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('A user connected')

    socket.on('findGame', data => {
        console.log(`Someone is finding a game! ${data}`)
    })
})

client:
import { useState } from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client'
import styles from './Game.module.scss'
const socket = io.connect('https://b76f-93-171-102-69.ngrok-free.app ')

export function Game() {
    const [cells, setCells] = useState(['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''])

    function changeCell(id) {
        const newCells = [...cells]
        newCells[id] = 'cross'
        setCells(newCells)
    }

    const cellParams = {
        cross: { style: styles.cross, path: '/src/assets/cross.svg' },
        circle: { style: styles.circle, path: '/src/assets/circle.svg' },
    }
    return (
        <div className={styles.game}>
            <div className={styles.gameInfo}>
                <h1>You Won!</h1>
                <p>Congratulations</p>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.gameField}>
                {cells.map((cell, index) => {
                    if (!(cell in cellParams))
                        return (
                            <button
                                className={styles.cell}
                                key={index}
                                onClick={() => changeCell(index)}
                            ></button>
                        )

                    const { style, path } = cellParams[cell]
                    return (
                        <button className={`${styles.cell} ${style}`} key={index}>
                            <img src={path} alt='' />
                        </button>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
            <button
                className={styles.gameButton}
                onClick={() => socket.emit('findGame', 'Привет')}
            >
                <img src='/src/assets/reset.svg' alt='' />
                Find a game
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}




добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос
